# Copy tables from access into excel spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I have an excel 2010 workbook, Verification Form, that I need to copy tables from Access 2010 into so that I can populate a form. I have three access tables – Dates, Activity, and Projects – and five excel sheets  – Raw Dates, Raw Activity, Raw Projects, Verification, and Parameters. The buttons are stored on the Parameters page.

I would like to write a VBA code that will copy the data from the tables in Access into the corresponding spreadsheet when a button, Get Data, is selected. Then, I want the sheets to be cleared when a Finish button is pressed. I've looked around online for a solution but so far I haven't found anything that works or helps.

Any assistance or pointers as to how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I'm trying to work with. It gives me an 'could not find installable ISAM' error at objDB.Execute.

```
Unload ParameterMenu
formWait.Show

'Save workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim strExcelFile As String
Dim strWorksheet As String
Dim strDB As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim objDB As Database

strExcelFile = "X:\Verification Form.xlsm"
strWorksheet = "RawDates"
strDB = "X:\Tables.accdb"
strTable = "Dates"

Set objDB = OpenDatabase(strDB)

'If excel file already exists, you can delete it here
'If Dir(strExcelFile) <> "" Then Kill strExcelFile

objDB.Execute _
  "SELECT * INTO [Excel 14.0;DATABASE=" & strExcelFile & _
   "].[" & strWorksheet & "] FROM " & "[" & strTable & "]"

objDB.Close
Set objDB = Nothing

Unload formWait
FinishDialog.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: What you're looking to do is achievable in a number of ways. What have you tried so far or what has your research revealed?

Comment: @Gareth I added the code I'm trying to work with but it's giving me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into opening the data as a `DAO.Recordset` and copying it to the range using the `.CopyFromRecordset` of the Range object.